# Ember - Can I use an Ember Component outside of a template?

Tags: templates, ember.js, components, render, public

Let's say I have a component called MyComponent. Is there anyway I can render that component into an outlet like I would with a regular template.

I am calling render from a Route. The reason I'm using a component is because I want to reuse a lot of my HTML, but also want to take advantage of the "public API" like aspects of components.

Can I achieve this with Ember?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can specify a template id or the actual template content itself in a view.  Instead of using the `templateName` property, set the `template` property lke this:

```
App.MyComponentView= Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{my-component}}");
});
```

Hope that helps.